# Substituting a Trigonometric Limit with an Algebraic one.

Tags: limits

Apparently, in many  cases such as $\lim_{x \to \frac{\pi}{2}}cosx$, replacing the limit by a variable that tends to be 0, as in the example:

> $\lim_{h \to 0}h$

this would be considered *wrong*, as, from the expansion of $cosx$, it would be nearer to:

> $\lim_{h \to 0}1-\frac{h}{2}$.

However, I still see multiple questions being solved by substituting limits as in the first method shown above.

Edit: For example, I've seen the following treatment; $\lim_{x \to \frac{\pi}{2}}sinx= \lim_{t \to 1}t$. This would imply $\lim_{h \to 0}1-h$ or  $\lim_{h \to 0}1+h$. Apparently, this is wrong.

Which one is ***correct*** and ***why***?

Comment: $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to \frac{\pi}2} \cos x = \lim_{h\to0} \cos(\tfrac{\pi}2+h)$ and not $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to \frac{\pi}2} \cos x = \lim_{h\to0} h$.

Comment: Added details to the question.